# Magento 2: How to pass custom params with url?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, currency, parameter, id

I want to pass custom params( product id and currency) with product page url dynamically.
 Example url:

https://example.com/boys-5-piece-blue-suit-eric.html?id=123&currency=GBP

Need help

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to Pass parameter

```
$id=123
$currency = 'GBP';
$parameter = ['id' => $id, 'currency' => $currency];
$resultRedirect->setPath('frontname/path/controllername', ['params' => $parameter]);
```

Comment: In which file this code should be place?

Comment: Where you want add redirect code . like block or controller file

Comment: I am new in magento 2, don't know where should be add this code to get example url.

Comment: I think you want add parameter on product details page . I am write ?

Comment: Yes.ID and currency(both) params on product detail page and just currency on all others pages.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to add id and currency then you have to work on `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url::getUrl()`

Create **Before plugin** on the method  `getUrl` and add `currency` add one of an index of parameter `$params`.

### Declare the Plugin from di.xml and it code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="StackExchange_MagentoAddress_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Model_Product_Url" 
                        sortOrder="10" type="StackExchange\Magento\Plugin\ProductUrl"/>
    </type>        
</config>
```

### Plugin Class

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Plugin;

class ProductUrl 
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
     \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager       
    ){

        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function beforeGetUrl(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url $subject,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
            $params = []
    ) {

        if(empty($params) || (!empty($params) && !array_key_exists('_query', $params))){

            if(!array_key_exists('_query', $params)){
                $params['_query'] = [];
            }
            if(!array_key_exists('currency', $params['_query'])){
                 $params['_query']['currency'] =$this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();
            }

        }

        return [
            $product,
            $params
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but not getting any result.

Comment: hmm i have checked that , seems it is not working. I will check again and will post answer

Comment: @shoaib-saleem,abve solution is worked

Comment: How to pass params in getUrl()?Can you describe a proper way?I am not good in Mag2.

Comment: using before plugin, i have changes the parameter of this function

Comment: I have been tested above solution, but didn't work for me.